# Creating Control on separate thread then adding to an itemsource in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, multithreading, ui-thread

I am creating a control on a separate STA thread in WPF and want to add it to a list then use the list as and itemssource for an itemscontrol.

My code runs fine until I try to show the control. I get an error saying that a different thread owns the list.

I fully understand why this is, but would like to know how I can get this back on to the UI thread.

My recurring Code:

```
For Each S In qry
    Dim T As New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Loader)
    T.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA)
    T.Start({S, AllBackgrounds})
Next
```

My Loader Sub:

```
Private Shared Sub Loader(O As Object)
    Dim ISC As New ImageSourceConverter
    Dim SI As New StudioImage
    SI.Source = ISC.ConvertFromString(O(0))
    CType(O(1), List(Of StudioImage)).Add(SI)
End Sub
```

So how can I get the List(Of StudioImage) back on to the UI thread?

Comment: you can't do this. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. If you want to show images, make sure you call `.Freeze()` on the Freezable if it was created on a background thread.

Comment: Why dont you look into the [Dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) class. This will allow you to pass data back to your UI thread.  Just dont create UI element on another thread and pass them over, think about how to pass the data, not the controls.

Answer (score 1):

> I am creating a control on a separate STA thread in WPF and want to add it to a list then use the list as and itemssource for an itemscontrol.

You can't do this.  The basic goal is flawed.

The problem is that you need to create all of the controls which will be used by WPF on the main UI thread.  In WPF, FrameworkElements all have thread affinity - they need to be created and used on the same thread.

In your case, the "work" you are doing all needs to happen on the UI thread.  Pushing this into background threads is never going to work properly, even if you were to properly synchronize (your code isn't thread safe, apart from the WPF side of things now).

You should just run your code entirely on the UI thread, unless there is the potential of pulling some small amount of work out that's not UI related (from what you're showing, this isn't the case).

---

Edit:

In your case, if you `Freeze()` your `ImageSource`, you can build the images in the background, but you can't bind them to the UI.

The following should handle this cleanly, without blocking the UI for parsing the image information.

```
For Each si In qry
    Dim s as String = si
    Dim t = Task.Factory.StartNew(Function() 
           Dim ISC As New ImageSourceConverter
           Dim is = ISC.ConvertFromString(s)
           is.Freeze()
           Return is
       End Function)
    t.ContinueWith(Function(a)
           Dim SI as New StudioImage
           SI.Source = a.Result
           AllBackgrounds.Add(SI)
       End Function, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext())
 Next
```

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that the UI is freezing for about 2 to 3 minutes while the list is populated. The images are high resolution coming over a network and there are about 40 images! How can I do this without interrupting the user experience? **Wireless network**

Comment: @richardharrison see my comment. You can create `ImageSource`s in a background thread, and then call Freeze() on them

Comment: ok, so I could create a List(Of ImageSource) in the background thread and call the .Freeze on each source. Then back on the UI thread create the controls using the List(Of ImageSource)?

Comment: @RichardHarrison again, don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code in WPF. That's what XAML is for. You can use an `ItemsControl` and bind the `ItemsSource` to an `ObservableCollection<ImageSource>` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the example. But unfortunately I'm now getting threading errors inside my StudioImage Control! I think I'll have to resort to using a progress bar and maybe some shopping mall music to entertain the users while the lists are populated!